# Sum records based in two variables

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to achieve the number of hits that was achieved in a month, I've tried several SUM formulas but I'm stuck, can you help me to solve this?
I've retrieved from DB the month 1 and month 2 total of hits, as you can see there are 2 source types, 1 and 2 and several hit types 1 to 6.
The goal is to find the number of hits for each type on the period grouped by the source.

```
Source  type        number         time
1        1          200            2015-02-01 00:00:25.000
1        2          350            2015-02-01 00:00:25.000
1        3           50            2015-02-01 00:00:25.000
1        4         1000            2015-02-01 00:00:25.000
2        1          360            2015-01-01 00:00:20.000
2        2           30            2015-01-01 00:00:20.000
2        3          500            2015-01-01 00:00:20.000
2        4          250            2015-01-01 00:00:20.000
1        1          200            2015-01-01 00:00:20.000
1        2          350            2015-01-01 00:00:20.000
1        3           50            2015-01-01 00:00:20.000
1        4         1000            2015-01-01 00:00:20.000
2        1          360            2015-02-01 00:00:25.000
2        2           30            2015-02-01 00:00:25.000
2        3          500            2015-02-01 00:00:25.000
2        4          250            2015-02-01 00:00:25.000
```

Ex
February Number of hits

```
Source1 Sum(type1+type4) of 2015-01-01  - Sum(type1+type4) of 2015-02-01
```

I know it seem confused but is the only way that I find to explain.

thanks in advance

carlos

Comment: It would be very helpful if you included the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking to split the amount into separate columns for each month?

```
select 
    Source, 
    sum(case when time >= '20150101' and time < '20150201' then number else 0 end) as Jan,
    sum(case when time >= '20150201' and time < '20150301' then number else 0 end) as Feb
from
    table
where
    type in (1,4)
group by
    source
```

if you need also separate columns with different types, then you have to add the type also to the case -statement.

Comment: Hi Team, It seem that some data was lost when I post the initial topic.

Comment: Hi JamesZ, with small changes works like a charme! that exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot for your prompt help.